# Cleaning Array without destroying structure

Tags: php, arrays, structure

I want to clean my array without destroying the structure. So I want to delete the values of each element. The problem is, that the array has more dimensions.

```
[array]
   [id] = "llll"
   [innerArray]
      [name] = "namenamename"
   [name] = "kdkdfk"
   [arryme]
      [id] = 121212
      [arraytarra] = "dd"
```

Should be

```
[array]
   [id] = ""
   [innerArray]
      [name] = ""
   [name] = ""
   [arryme]
      [id] = 0
      [arraytarra] = ""
```

---

This is my beginning:

```
private function cleanArray($array) {

    $return = $array;

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if(is_Array($array[$key])) $this->cleanArray($array[$key]);
        else $return[$key] = "";
    }

}
```

---

Final version, thanks to bwoebi:

```
 /****************
 * cleanArray()
 ****************
 *   cleans an array: deletes the values but let the keys
 */
private function cleanArray($array) {

    foreach($array as &$value) {

        if(is_Array($value)) $value = $this->cleanArray($value);
        else if(is_Int($value)) $value = 0;
        else if(is_Bool($value)) $value = false;
        else $value = "";
    }

    return $array;

}
```

Comment: You can access multi-dimensional values using [array][innerArray][name] = ""

Comment: Of course I know this :) But I can't code the script for that. I added my beginning in the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private function cleanArray($array) {

    foreach($array as &$value) {

        if(is_Array($value))
            $value = $this->cleanArray($value);
        else
            $value = "";
    }

    return $array;

}
```

Your beginning nearly does it (only small modifications were needed), but you don't have to copy the array. As you don't have a reference operator in your parameter list, the array will be passed by value.

You also can simply use the array values by reference in your foreach loop. And don't forget: save the returned array into a variable. And return your final array also. You don't return anything because it's named `$return`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm too long on PC now, so I didn't saw the last easy step. I expand your version, so I don't loose the type-information of the value.

Comment: @DavidPauli If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: @bwoebi Thanks, didn't know it yet. I'm new here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer would be a recursive function the sets each value null or a null string. Here's an example of a recursive function that does something different, but should be a decent starting place for you.

http://tecbrat.blogspot.com/2013/03/recursive-function-to-find-substrings.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can loop inside your array and create a new array while iterating, preserving keys and updating values as `NULL`

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $key => $data)
{
    $new_array[$key] = NULL;
    if(is_array($data))
    {
        foreach($data as $keys => $val)
        {
            $new_array[$key][$keys] = NULL;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

this will output

```
array (size=4)
  'id' => null
  'innerArray' => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => null
  'name' => null
  'arryme' => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => null
      'arraytarra' => null
```

#### [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/Andhtv)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code. Performance wise it's not optimal but looks great as art of code.

```
function cleanArray($a) 
{
    return is_array($a) ? array_map("cleanArray", $a) : "";
}
$b = array_map("cleanArray", $array);
```